# Why invalidate is not working?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am trying to click a button and add a resistor. So what I need is to invalidate the view when the button is clicked. But the invalidate that is inside `MyView` inside the method `update()` is not working. I have been trying to search for this problem but I have found nothing similar to what I am trying to do, or maybe this is not the way to do it.

*DefaultActivity.java*

```
public class DefaulActivity extends Activity {       

  MyView myView;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    myView = new MyView(this, null); 

    final Button bAddResistor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    bAddResistor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click              
            myView.update();                            
            Log.d("ButtonADD", "Button Add has been clicked");
        }
    });          
  } 
}
```

*MyView.java*

```
public class MyView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{      


  Resistor myResistor;
  private ArrayList<Resistor> mElements = new ArrayList<Resistor>();


  public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);  
    getHolder().addCallback(this);  

  } 

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    super.onDraw(canvas);

    synchronized (mElements) {
        for (Resistor element : mElements) {
            element.doDraw(canvas);                
        }
    }   

  }

  public void update() {

       mElements.add(new Resistor(getContext(), (int) 10, (int) 10));
       invalidate(); //Does not work!
  }


  @Override
  public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @Override
  public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
    onDraw(c);      
    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);      
  }

  @Override
  public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

  } 

}
```

*Resistor.java*

```
public class Resistor extends View{

  private Path mSymbol;
  private Paint mPaint;

  private int mX;
  private int mY;

  //...Override Constructors...    
  public Resistor(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
  }

  public Resistor(Context context, int x, int y){
    super(context);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
    init();
  }

  private void init() {
    mSymbol = new Path();
    mPaint = new Paint();

    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);      
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    mPaint.setColor(-7829368);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    //...Your code here to set up the path,
    //...allocate objects here, never in the drawing code.

    mSymbol.moveTo(0.0F, 0.0F);
    mSymbol.lineTo(0.0F, 50.0F);
    mSymbol.lineTo(16.666666F, 58.333332F);
    mSymbol.lineTo(-16.666666F, 75.0F);
    mSymbol.lineTo(16.666666F, 91.666664F);
    mSymbol.lineTo(-16.666666F, 108.33333F);
    mSymbol.lineTo(16.666666F, 124.99999F);
    mSymbol.lineTo(-16.666666F, 141.66666F);
    mSymbol.lineTo(0.0F, 150.0F);
    mSymbol.lineTo(0.0F, 200.0F);
    mSymbol.offset(mX, mY);

  }

  public void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawPath(mSymbol, mPaint);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `ViewGroup` instead of a `SurfaceView`. Add the `Resistor`-Views as children to `MyView`, [measure and layout them appropriately](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) and the `ViewGroup` will automatically take care of drawing them.

`SurfaceView` requires you to do your drawing in a seperate thread. You have to start that thread in `surfaceCreated` and keep redrawing the view as needed. For simple views like the one you posted it is perfectly acceptable to just do your drawing in the UI thread. No `SurfaceView` required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try to use ViewGroup to see how would that work. So if I want to keep using SurfaceView I need to create a separate thread? and then I would be able to do what I wanted to do above?

Comment: Essentially, yes. For example, you could make a thread with a endless loop that continuously redraws the view. That would obviously be very bad news for your CPU, though. SurfaceView is for very special drawing needs, for example a Browser or a Map that needs to redraw tiles as soon as they have been rendered by a background thread. You usually won't need it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Surfaceviews before but if you in the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) you can see, that there is no function called "invalidate()" for the SurfaceView class.

Maybe you can manage to re-use this line somehow:

```
holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
```

Comment: You're actually wrong here as `SurfaceView` extends `View` and one of the inherited methods is `invalidate()`.